# error: strstream.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, gcc

I am trying to run an old C++ code in Linux (Redhat). I am using gcc version 4.1.2.

I got the following error:

```
error: strstream.h: No such file or directory
/trnuser1/rmtrain/DevelopmentEnv/Generic/CoreObjects/GCVTransformationServices.cpp:41: error: âostrstreamâ was not declared in this scope
/trnuser1/rmtrain/DevelopmentEnv/Generic/CoreObjects/GCVTransformationServices.cpp:41: error: expected `;' before âstrDestXMLâ
/trnuser1/rmtrain/DevelopmentEnv/Generic/CoreObjects/GCVTransformationServices.cpp:62: error: âstrDestXMLâ was not declared in this scope
```

This code was running fine under Solaris with gcc version 2.95. The line pointed to by the error contains the following statement:

```
ostrstream strDestXML;
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Probably `#include <sstream>` and `std::ostringstream strDestXML;`.

Comment: 1) 4.1.2 is **old**. Get newer compiler. 2) Standard C++ Headers don't have extension.

Comment: @hmjd why not an answer?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, though I am confident I am not 100% certain.

Comment: Note that what gcc 2.95 compiled was not standard c++, but what gcc 4.x compile is (almost) standard c++, so basically both compilers support(ed) different languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `#include <strstream>` (note absence of the '.h' suffix).
But if you want to properly port the code to modern C++, you should consider changing this to `#include <sstream>` and `std::ostringstream strDestXML;` as suggested in the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Standard C++ headers do not have extension.

```
#include <sstream>
```

Standard classes are contained in `std` namespace:

```
std::ostringstream strDestXML;
```

Finally, `strstream` is deprecated; use `stringstream` instead - that's why I used it here.

---

And, just a note about GCC version - 4.1.2 is **old**, no matter what - use something newer.

Answer (score 2):

The modern name for this include is `<strstream>`.  (Although it's formally deprecated, it's still required.)  The classes it defines are in namespace `std`, and have slightly different semantics than the classical iostream, so you may have to do a little bit of modification later anyway.  (Depending on how it is being used, it might make sense to change to `<sstream>`, replacing `[io]strstream` with `std::[io]stringstream`.)